# Unlock a Veracrypt/Truecrypt partition which uses a keyfile with a passphrase from /etc/crypttab

Tags: linux, truecrypt, veracrypt

I have a Veracrypt (/Truecrypt) volume, which I can successfully unlock manually by providing a key file and passphrase:

```
# cryptsetup --type tcrypt --key-file /.keyfile open /dev/nvme0n1p5 shared
Enter passphrase for /dev/nvme0n1p5:
```

Only root has `rw` on the key file, a binary file of 64 bytes.

```
# ls -l /.keyfile
-rw------- 1 root root 64 aug 21 08:09 /.keyfile
# file /.keyfile
/.keyfile: data
# du -b /.keyfile
64  /.keyfile
```

Is there a way to unlock a Veracrypt (/Truecrypt, `/dev/nvme0n1p5` in my case) partition that uses a key file with a password in `/etc/crypttab`?

I have tried constructing a file with the structure `{passphrase}{newline}{key file contents}` and manually using it to unlock as above, but I still got the passphrase question. To create that file, I did the following:

```
# echo 'mypassword' > /.keyfile_psw
# cat /.keyfile >> /.keyfile_psw
```